# LEFT JOIN - How to join tables and include extra row even if you have right match

Tags: sql

I have two tables

```
Table A
-------
ID
ProductName

Table B
-------
ID
ProductID
Size
```

I want to join these two tables

```
SELECT * FROM
   (SELECT * FROM A)
   LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT * FROM B)
ON A.ID = B.ProductID
```

This is easy, I will get all rows from A multiplied by rows matched in B, and NULL fields if there is no match.

But here comes the tricky question, how can I get all rows from A with NULL fields for table B, even if there is a match, so I get an extra line with NULL values plus all the matches?

Comment: Can you give a desired output plz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `UNION ALL` in a subquery as suggested by others, you could also (and I would) use `UNION ALL` at the outer level, which keeps the query simpler:

```
SELECT A.ID, A.ProductName, B.ID, B.Size
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
ON B.ProductID = A.ID
UNION ALL
SELECT A.ID, A.ProductName, NULL, NULL
FROM A
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT  A.* 
,       B3.ID
,       B3.ProductID
,       B3.Size
FROM    A
LEFT JOIN
        (
        SELECT  ProductID as MatchID
        ,       ID
        ,       ProductID
        ,       Size 
        FROM    B
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  ID
        ,       null
        ,       null
        ,       null
        FROM    A A2
        ) B3
ON      A.ID = B3.MatchID
```

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88d2c/5/0)

Answer (score 1):

Since every join is going to be successful, we can switch to a full/inner join:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
   A
       INNER JOIN
   (SELECT ID,ProductID,Size FROM B
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL,ID,NULL FROM A) B
       ON
          A.ID = B.ProductID
```

Now would be a *very* good time to switch to naming columns explicitly, rather than using `SELECT *`

---

Or, if, as per @Andomar's comment, you need all of the `B` columns to be `NULL`:

```
SELECT
    A.ID,A.ProductName,
    B.ID,B.ProductID,B.Size
FROM
   A
       INNER JOIN
   (SELECT ID,ProductID,Size,ProductID as MatchID FROM B
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL,NULL,NULL,ID FROM A) B
       ON
          A.ID = B.MatchID
```

Comment: This would return a non-null value in B's `ProductID` for the extra row.  I think you need an extra alias just to join on.

Comment: @Andomar - I've added that as an option. It's a weird requirement though (and I'm still assuming that the `ID` columns are PKs in their respective tables)